# Unable to perform any WLAN-related operations from core1 on Pi Pico with Micropython 1.20

Tags: micropython, pi-pico-w

The following code snippet correctly sets up the Pico Pi W as an AP when run on the main core (core0)

```
def connect():
    ssid = 'MicroPython-AP'
    password = '123456789'
    #Connect to WLAN
    print("about to call network.WLAN")
    ap = network.WLAN(network.AP_IF)
    print("called network.WLAN")
    ap.config(essid=ssid, password=password)
    print("configured ap")
    ap.active(True)
    print("set ap active")
    print(ap.ifconfig())
    return ap
```

However when run on core1, whether or not the code is guarded by a lock, the line ap.active(true) never returns and the AP does not appear in the wifi connection list

If the ap is created on core0 and then the following code is used to set up two UDP sockets also on core0

```
    ap = connect()
    socket1 = open_socket(ap.ifconfig()[0], 5004)
    socket2 = open_socket(ap.ifconfig()[0], 5005)
    poller = select.poll()
    poller.register(socket1, select.POLLIN)
    poller.register(socket2, select.POLLIN)
```

If we then pass the poller to a new thread function on core1,
then code which works correctly on core0 to then poll i.e as shown below, shows that the timeout on the poll does occur, but UDP datagrams are not received. Again this is regardless of whether the code is guarded by a lock.
The code works perfectly when run from core0

```
while True:
    res = poller.poll(1000)  # time in milliseconds
    while not res:
        print("wait for socket")          
        res = poller.poll(1000)
    for s in res:
        data, address = s[0].recvfrom(1024)
```